# Displaying character when read into file - encoding

Tags: java, swing, file, character-encoding

I have a problem with the encoding of text when I display it into my text area.

The problem is when there are character like : `é à è`

I have in my text area `? ? ?` instead

Here is the part of code to read  my file :

```
private void importerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(0);
    try {

        JFileChooser explorer = new JFileChooser(chemin);
        int answer = explorer.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (answer == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            chemin = explorer.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

             String name = explorer.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();
            System.out.println("name : "+name);

             texte.setText("");
             File file = new File(name);
             try {
             DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
             String result = in.readUTF();
             texte.setText(result);
             in.close();
             System.out.println("Erreur la");
             } catch (IOException e) {
             DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
             String result = null;
             result = "";
             byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
             int read = in.read(buff, 0, 2048);
             while (read >= 0) {
             String substr = new String(buff, 0, read);
             result += substr;
             read = in.read(buff, 0, 2048);
             }
             // System.out.println(result);
             Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
             result = charset.decode(charset.encode(result)).toString();
             texte.setText(result);
             in.close();
             //System.out.println("Erreur la2");
             }              
        }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erreur lors du chargement du fichier", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

My textarea is : `texte.setText(result);`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: After some deliberation, I have decided this is Swing.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your line `String substr = new String(buff, 0, read);` should have been `String substr = new String(buff, 0, read,"UTF-8");`

Comment: See also [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) *"Initializes from a stream. .."*.

Comment: utf-8 isn't EncodePage that is used for File

Answer (score 0):

If your file encoding is UTF-8 then simply read it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868528/1360074)

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  result += line;
}
br.close();

texte.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Charset.encode method expects a string in unicode format. In fact all strings in java are supposed to be unicode (utf16).
Do this

```
String substr = new String(buff, 0, read, "UTF-8");
```

And remove all the charset.encode/decode code.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `String substr = new String(buff, 0, read);` should have been

```
String substr = new String(buff, 0, read,"UTF-8");
```

Constructor `String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)` constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes using the platform's default charset.